# how to set a value of a column by different rows

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

here is my data example:

| SN | test case | measure | test result |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| SN1 | TC1 |  | Fail |
| SN1 | TC1 | value1 | Pass |
| SN1 | TC2 | value2 | Pass |
| SN2 | TC1 | value1 | Pass |
| SN2 | TC2 |  | Fail |
| SN2 | TC2 | value2 | Pass |

you can see in the data that the failed cases are passed by retesting the case.
what i want to do is to identify that which passed cases are retested cases.

so i want to add another column named 'retest' and only marked the retested cases as 1, others as 0.

| SN | test case | measure | test result | retest |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| SN1 | TC1 |  | Fail | 0 |
| SN1 | TC1 | value1 | Pass | 1 |
| SN1 | TC2 | value2 | Pass | 0 |
| SN2 | TC1 | value1 | Pass | 0 |
| SN2 | TC2 |  | Fail | 0 |
| SN2 | TC2 | value2 | Pass | 1 |

so the values in the column 'retest' are depended on the different rows and different columns.

i've tried to use df.apply(), but it can only pass one row to the function. and it is not efficiency, if i use for loop, for there are more than 56M rows in the database.

is there any efficient way to use pandas to achieve this task?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```py
failed_before = (df["test result"]
                   .eq("Fail")
                   .groupby([df["SN"], df["test case"]])
                   .transform("any"))

passed = df["test result"].eq("Pass")

df["retest"] = (passed & failed_before).astype(int)
```

- check for each SN & test_case pair to see if they have *any* failings

  - with `transform`, this is spread to each row of the unique SN & test_case pairs
- check if a given row has status "Pass"

  - both steps give a True/False result
- since "retested === passed now but also had a failure", we AND the two conditions

  - result is True/False's, cast to integers at the end

to get

```
>>> df

    SN test case measure test result  retest
0  SN1       TC1     NaN        Fail       0
1  SN1       TC1  value1        Pass       1
2  SN1       TC2  value2        Pass       0
3  SN2       TC1  value1        Pass       0
4  SN2       TC2     NaN        Fail       0
5  SN2       TC2  value2        Pass       1
```

(assumes there's no failure once passed in a given SN & test_case pair.)

---

When you have a GroupBy object, it doesn't really do anything on its own; you need to do something further to generate results out of it. `.agg` is one way of doing it: it will aggregate per-group results (`.apply` is another similar one). There's also this `.transform`. Let's see for your data what `.agg` does after a groupby operation:

```py
# without transform, but agg
df["test result"].eq("Fail").groupby([df["SN"], df["test case"]]).agg("any")

SN   test case
SN1  TC1           True
     TC2          False
SN2  TC1          False
     TC2           True
Name: test result, dtype: bool
```

- so we first checked equality against "Fail" as before
- then group that result over "SN" and "test case" pairs

  - at this point, groupby object is "lazy" so to speak
  - now comes the action...
- ...we aggregate each group's result to produce a single value out of them

  - in this case we do it with "any"
  - i.e., "if there were at least one True in a given group, give True for this group (e.g., for SN1-TC1); otherwise (when all are False), give False for the group (e.g., SN1-TC2)

Now, you see that we have a 4 row result at the end. Why? Because that's how many *unique* SN-test_case pairs there are! "SN1-TC1", "SN1-TC2", "SN2-TC1" and "SN2-TC2". That's fine: we got a single result for each group.

However, what if you want to *repeat* that single result for each occurences of a given group in the original dataframe? As we see, the original dataframe has 6 rows: this implies some groups have records more than once (actually those are "SN1-TC1" and "SN2-TC2"). Hmm... so we need a result that has the same number of rows as the original dataframe, while repeating this aggregation result for each group as many as needed. That's where transform comes into play:

```py
df["test result"].eq("Fail").groupby([df["SN"], df["test case"]]).transform("any")

0     True
1     True
2    False
3    False
4     True
5     True
Name: test result, dtype: bool
```

You see how we got a 6-row result? Previously, we got a True value for "SN1-TC1" with `.agg` but it was only showing it once. Now, it *repeats* that True value for each "SN1-TC1" pair in the original dataframe, i.e., at indexes 0 and 1 here. Similar goes for all the groups, and we get a len(df) length result.

Now comes "why" do we need to transform? Because as you see in the code above further, we needed to compare `passed` with `failed_before`. Now, `passed` is nothing but `df["test result"].eq("Pass")` -- this is a True/False Series of the same length as `df`. It telss for each row of "test result" that whether it had a "Pass" status or not. Cool. We want to compare this to `failed_before` values: if we had `.agg` and produce a single result for unique group members, there would be a length mismatch! It has 4 rows because 4 unique values, but we need full 6 rows to compare against `passed` -- and that's where `transform` helps us by repeating the aggregated values as necessary to enable comparison.

Lastly, both `agg` and `transform` take an arbitrary function to perform on groups; however, some functionalities are so common that they have string shortcuts like "any", "all", "mean", "sum", "unique" etc. IOW, we could have done `lambda gr: gr.any()` instead of `"any"` above in both agg or transform, but "any" is at our disposal as a convenience. (As an aside, GroupBy.agg can take a list of functions etc. as mentioned [in its documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.SeriesGroupBy.aggregate.html), but that's not really related to the distinction here.)

Comment: hi Mustafa, thank you for you answer, and it really help me out of the problem. after checking the official doc of pandas about the transform, i haven't found the usage of transform("any"). the 'any' is supposed to be a function. and you've said that the transform is spread to each row. could you please explain more about what has been spread to each row, and how can i learn the detail of the usage of transform('any')

Comment: hi @user20432160, glad it helps. I tried to write about what is transform doing, how is it different than agg, and why would you use it as an edit to the answer, hope it helps.

Comment: hi Mustafa, thank you for your detail information. i will learn it carefully.